# In JavaFX how do i set label alignment inside a tab?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

It is graphic+text inside tabs.

The TabPane is made in the fxml :

```
<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" rotateGraphic="true" side="LEFT" stylesheets="@Scene1.css" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="vues.Scene1Controller">
  <tabs>
    <Tab fx:id="tab111" text="Text1">
      <graphic>
        <ImageView>
          <image>
            <Image url="@face.png" />
          </image>
        </ImageView>
      </graphic>
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="but111" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="64.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#but111Action" text="Button" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Text222222222222222222">
      <graphic>
        <ImageView>
          <image>
            <Image url="@face.png" />
          </image>
        </ImageView>
      </graphic>
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

and some css :

```
.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-width:300px;
    -fx-tab-max-width:300px;
    -fx-tab-min-height:300px;
    -fx-tab-max-height:300px;
}
.tab *.tab-label {
    -fx-rotate: 90;
    /* -fx-content-display: left; */
    /* -fx-padding: 0 0 0 -60; */
    /* -fx-translate-y: -100; */
    /* -fx-graphic-text-gap: 30px; */
    /* -fx-layout-y: 150; */


}
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:hover > .tab-container > .tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-graphic: url("face33.png");
}
```

And the result is this :

[image: not well aligned - centered]

Now my problem is that i want that aligned left, but the pick point of this, lets say, label, is center, so if i translate this to left with fixed value, they will not be aligned to left, but from center (using "-fx-translate-y: -150;" (height of 300 / 2)), and here is the result :

[image: not well aligned - with translate]

I cant use a custom translate value for each, because the text will be variable.

Comment: `.tab .tab-label { -fx-alignment: left;}` doesn't work?

Comment: this line = Caught java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant javafx.geometry.Pos.left' while calculating value for '-fx-alignment' from rule '*.tab *.tab-label' in stylesheet
but i just tried with baseline-left, then nothing happens, and with only .tab also, but with 
.tab-label { -fx-alignment: baseline-left; }
it changes just little bit
i wish i could post a video instead of typing, it seems like an easy task for a javafx expert :D